# In a type alias for an object type are the properties separated by semicolon (;) or by comma (,)?

Tags: typescript, syntax

I just started learning TypeScript, so I have a question about syntax.

In a type alias for an object type are the properties separated by semicolon (;) or by comma (,)?

I see from [The TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html), that `;` is used.

```
// object literal type
type Person = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};
```

However, in other code samples on the web, for example [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/typescript/typescript_aliases_and_interfaces.php), I see comma (,).

```
type CarYear = number
type CarType = string
type CarModel = string
type Car = {
  year: CarYear,
  type: CarType,
  model: CarModel
}
```

I thought this code with the comma was wrong, but it seems to transpile fine into JavaScript.

By the way, in these similar-looking, but actually *different* cases, a comma is correct.

```
// inferred type from setting to an object literal
const car = {
  year: 2009,
  type: "Toyota"
};

// defining an object while using a type alias.
const car: Car = {
  year: 2009,
  type: "Toyota"
};

// tuple type
type Data = [
  location: Location,
  timestamp: string
];
```

But back to the main question:
For separating the properties in a type alias for an object type,
is comma(,) just wrong?  Or also acceptable?  And why?

Comment: For `type`s, they are both are syntactically valid. Also valid is leaving off the separators entirely. Which you prefer is up to you.

Comment: IMHO just let [prettier](https://prettier.io/) decide for you and not worry about it.

Comment: Either way is fine, see linked question/answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatters by default will go toward the use of the semicolon:

```
type CarYear = number;
type CarType = string;
type CarModel = string;
type Car = {
  year: CarYear;
  type: CarType;
  model: CarModel;
};

type Person = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};
```